# Netsh doesn't set ip on specific interface

Tags: c, winapi, interface, cygwin

Here is my code which creates a netowork interface

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winerror.h>
#include <Winbase.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef BOOL WINAPI (*InstallSelectedDriverProto)(HWND, HDEVINFO, LPCTSTR, BOOL, PDWORD);

int main()
{
  InstallSelectedDriverProto InstallSelectedDriver;

  static const int MAX_NAME = 256;

  HDEVINFO devices = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

  char infPath[260] = {0};

  char deviceId[260] = {0};

  DWORD reboot = 0;

  HMODULE Dll = NULL;

  int devNameSize = 260;

  GUID classGUID = {0};

  char ClassName[MAX_NAME] = {0};

  char hwIdList[LINE_LEN + 4] = {0};

  SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceData = {0};

  SP_DRVINFO_DATA driverInfoData = {sizeof(SP_DRVINFO_DATA)};

  const char *hwid;

  char *devName = NULL;

  char deviceName[260];

  hwid = "tsu";

  char *inf;

  inf = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TSU\\tsu.inf";

  strncpy(infPath, inf, sizeof(infPath)-1);

  infPath[sizeof(infPath)-1] = '\0';

  memset(hwIdList, 0, sizeof(hwIdList));

  strcpy(hwIdList, hwid);

  DWORD resultant;

  if (SetupDiGetINFClass(infPath, &classGUID,
                              ClassName, MAX_NAME, 0) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiGetINFClass failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }
  devices = SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(&classGUID, 0);

  if (devices == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    printf("devices == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }

  deviceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

  if (devName == NULL || devName[0] == 0)
  {
    if (SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo(devices, hwid, &classGUID, "yverichita", 0,
                                     DICD_GENERATE_ID, &deviceData) == FALSE)
    {
      printf("SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stdout);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  else
  {
    strcpy(deviceId, "Root\\");

    strcat(deviceId, ClassName);
    strcat(deviceId, "\\");
    strcat(deviceId, devName);

    if (SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo(devices, deviceId, &classGUID,
                                     "yverichita", 0, 0, &deviceData) == FALSE)
    {
      printf("SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stdout);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  if (SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty(devices, &deviceData,
                                            SPDRP_HARDWAREID, (BYTE *) hwIdList,
                                                (strlen(hwIdList) + 2)) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }

  if (SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_REGISTERDEVICE,
                                     devices, &deviceData) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiCallClassInstaller failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }

  AddDriverPackage(infPath);

  Dll = LoadLibrary("Newdev.dll");

  if (Dll == NULL)
  {
    printf("Dll == NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }

  InstallSelectedDriver = (InstallSelectedDriverProto) GetProcAddress(Dll, "InstallSelectedDriver");

  if (InstallSelectedDriver == NULL)
  {
    printf("InstallSelectedDriver == NULL failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }

  if (SetupDiSetSelectedDevice(devices, &deviceData) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiSetSelectedDevice failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }

  if (SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList(devices, &deviceData,
                                        SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }

  if (SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV, devices,
                                       &deviceData) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }


  if (SetupDiGetSelectedDriver(devices, &deviceData,
                                      &driverInfoData) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiGetSelectedDriver failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }


  if (InstallSelectedDriver(NULL, devices, NULL, TRUE, &reboot) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("InstallSelectedDriver failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }
  if (SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(devices, &deviceData,
                                    deviceName, devNameSize, NULL) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 1;
  }

  printf("SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId: Name used: %s\n", deviceName);
  fflush(stdout);

  return 0;

 }
```

Then I'm using netsh to change its name and then set its ip.I'm using following commands:
`netsh.exe interface set interface name="Local Area Connection 69" newname="Network #1"`
this command runs without a problem, I checked from GUI too and interface is clearly created and name is changed correctly. Then I run:
`netsh interface ip set address name="Network #1" static 192.168.1.92 255.255.255.252 none`
which gives me back error saying:
`failed to configure the dhcp service. The interface may be disconnected. System cannot find file speciified.`
after some debugging I noticed that If I choose name `Network #5` for example everything works fine, name is set correctly and setting ip works ok. I've searched around what could be the cause of it and thought that maybe the problem is in netsh so I tried to [reset](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx) it, but unfortunately It didn't work, I even installed fresh windows on vmware and tried running this code there, everything worked fine, It's clearly "some things left" undeleted and it causes some problem. 
 I'm using Windows, Cygwin. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of the netsh error but the IP address 192.168.1.92 /30 is a network address and not an assignable IP address. Have you tried using IP address 192.168.1.93 or 192.168.1.94 instead?

Comment: I just looked up one of my server core configurations where I seemed to have used the `ipv4 set` subcommand of netsh instead of `ip set`. You coul try to see if the following command works: `netsh interface ipv4 set address "network #1" static 192.168.1.93 255.255.255.252`